# Write a C++ program which will print (half pyramid) pattern of natural numbers

Tags: c++

The task:
Write a C++ program which will print (half pyramid) pattern of natural numbers.

```
1
2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
```

I have tried using this code, but its not giving the output:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int rows, i, j;
    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    for(i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << j << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter number of rows: 5
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Okay: please explain what input you give to your program, what happens, and what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: `for(j = 1;`: you are reinitializing `j` to 1 every time this for loop begins, so of course the number starts over at 1.  You probably want a separate counter variable in place of `j` that you increment every step and don't reinitialize.

Comment: Change `for(j = 1` to `for(j = i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`j` in your inner loop is the 1 based index of the element in the current row (1,2,3 etc.).
Instead of printing it, you should print a counter that is increased over all the iterations.

**Something like:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int rows, i, j;
    std::cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    std::cin >> rows;
    int n = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            std::cout << n << " ";
            n++;  // for next iteration
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output example:**

```
Enter number of rows: 5
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

**A side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).